# Blogs and Books on Encryption and Security

Tags: security, math, encryption

Could any of you experienced programmers / ethical hackers out there recommend some blogs or books on security/encryption? The only blogs I look at now are,

- [.Net Security Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2009/03/17/authenticated-symmetric-encryption-in-net.aspx).
- [Laptop Security Blog](http://blog.absolute.com/cybercrimes-more-sophisticated-but-so-too-are-countermeasures/).
- [Schneier On Security](http://www.schneier.com/index.html).

I am especially interested in the mathematical theory behind the security/encryption, not just how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For encryption I highly recommend the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/), which you can either buy as a book or download all of the chapters for free at the linked address.  In addition the University of Washington released the full semesters worth of lectures from their [Practical Aspects of Modern Cryptography](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/csep590/06wi/) class as a podcast (MP3 format), it should still be available on iTunes or elsewhere.

Other great sources of security information are:

- [OWASP Podcast](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Podcast)
- [Silver Bullet Podcast](http://www.cigital.com/silverbullet/)
- [Insecure Magazine](http://www.net-security.org/insecuremag.php)
- [Matasano Chargen](http://www.matasano.com)
- [Tales from the Crypto](http://msmvps.com/blogs/alunj)
- [The New School of Information Security](http://newschoolsecurity.com)
- [www.leastprivilege.com](http://www.leastprivilege.com)

Answer (score 4):

If you enjoy Schneier you'll probably enjoy his encryption books, in addition to the relevant [material on his website](http://www.schneier.com/)

In particular [Practical Cryptography](http://www.schneier.com/book-practical.html) (2003) and [Applied Cryptography](http://www.schneier.com/book-applied.html) (1996)

If you are an [ACM](http://www.acm.org/) Professional Member you currently have free access to Modern Cryptanalysis: Techniques for Advanced Code Breaking by Christopher Swenson in the Books24x7 selection (from MyACM).

Comment: +1 Applied Cryptography is a masterpiece

Answer (score 2):

Some books I can recommend:

- [The Codebreakers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0684831309) by David Kahn
- [The Code Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0385495323) by Simon Singh
- [Applied Cryptography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471117099) by Bruce Schneier
- [The Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/)

I also recommend the [Security Now](http://twit.tv/sn) podcast with Leo Laporte and Steve Gibson.  Here's a particularly good sequence of episodes on cryptography:

- [Episode 30: Crypto Issues](http://twit.tv/sn30)
- [Episode 31: Crypto 102](http://twit.tv/sn31)
- [Episode 33: Symmetric Block Ciphers](http://twit.tv/sn33)
- [Episode 34: Public Key Cryptography](http://twit.tv/sn34)
- [Episode 35: Cryptographic Hashes](http://twit.tv/sn35)
- [Episode 37: Primes and Certificates](http://twit.tv/sn37)